# Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime with 2 nodes in different locations

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have am trying to set up Data Factory between the on premise SQL Server on a corporate network and a SQL Server hosted in an Azure VM (not MI).
Is this possible? I set up both nodes on the IR and opened firewall port 8060 both on premise and in the Azure VM.

My goal is to copy data as needed from the on premise sql server to the sql server hosted in the azure vm.

I am getting this error

> This node has some connectivity issue with the dispatcher node. Please check the connectivity between the nodes within your network.
> The Integration Runtime (Self-hosted) node is trying to sync the credentials across nodes. It may take several minutes.
> If this warning appears for over 10 minutes, please check the connectivity with Dispatcher node.

Answer (score 0):

In my case port 8060 is being blocked by the corporate firewall, not the server firewall.  Since I can't change the corporate firewall, I'll use a different work around.  However I can't find a good demo of this working in two separate networks. All the demos use Azure VM's, so I was hoping to test out a real life example.